# Array with multivalue in each row-php

Tags: php, database

How can I create an array in PHP that contains 2 values in each row (dynamically). I mean I do not know the number of array rows.

```
  Row1: x,y
  Row2: x,y
  Row3: x,y
  Row n : x,y
```

I try:

```
$arr = array(
    array('x', 'y'),
    array('x', 'y'),
    array('x', 'y'),
 );
```

but, I did not know the number of array rows.

And how to insert the 2 values of each array row in a database row?

Any help?

Comment: You know that an array can have multiple elements? Now consider an array whose elements are arrays with multiple elements. That is what you asked for.

Comment: I try $result[$x]=$y;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => x
        [1] => y
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => x
        [1] => y
    )

 [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => x
        [1] => y
    )

 )
```

Then you could try:

```
 $arr = array(
    array('x', 'y'),
    array('x', 'y'),
    array('x', 'y'),
 );

 echo "<pre>";

 print_r($arr);
```

---

Inserting multiple rows:

```
$arr = array(
    array('x', 'y'),
    array('x', 'y'),
    array('x', 'y'),
 );

$fields = implode(', ', array_shift($arr));

$values = array();

foreach ($array as $rowValues) {

   foreach ($rowValues as $key => $rowValue) {
       $rowValues[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($rowValues[$key]);
    }
   $values[] = "(" . implode(', ', $rowValues) . ")";
}

$query = "INSERT INTO table_name ($fields) VALUES " . implode (', ', $values);
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: Inserting? Could you be a bit more accurate, please?

Comment: As i ask in my post inserting into database

Comment: I try for one dimensional array: foreach($result as $resultcount => $target_name){
    Insert statement}. What about multidimensional array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106146/discussion-between-alaa-and-object-manipulator).